# Prevent redownloading Gradle after moving it to secondary drive when using Cordova?

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle, windows-10

I moved `Sdk` and `.gradle` folders installed by Android Studio from `c:` to `d:` disk and after configuring the paths in Android Studio that worked well.

The problem was when I then tried to build an existing Cordova project outside of Android Studio by using:

`cordova build android`

because there was an error `Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio` so I had to add the path to the Gradle `bin` folder to the `path` environment variable and then compile worked well but during the process the `.gradle` folder was again recreated on the `c:` drive and the files were again downloaded there.

Is there a way to configure the system so the Cordova could work with the new location of `.gradle` directory? It seems to me that now after I moved the `.gradle` folder and specified the location of the `bin` folder by adding it to the `path`, Gradle updates from within Android Studio will not be taken into account and seems that the mechanism for Cordova accessing the Gradle is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` and point it to another directory.

Source: http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2010/09/gradle-goodness-changing-gradle-user.html